# R Shiny: Selective outputs assignment inside loops and IF statements

Tags: r, if-statement, while-loop, shiny, output

I have a shiny app that calls a script which iterates producing a figure in each iteration. I need to show each plot and tried using recordPlot to save each plot to a list and call every element individually but the objects are not recognized later by the app. Then I also tried to include the different outputs in IF statements but my algorithm only produces the last plot for all outputs, it is like the IF statements are being ignored and I don't know howto deal whit it. Here is a simplification of my code:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      actionButton("exec", "Start!!"),
      tagList(tags$h4("First iteration:")),
              plotOutput('PlotIter1'),
              tags$hr(),
              tagList(tags$h4("Second iteration:")),
              plotOutput('PlotIter2'),
              tags$hr(),
              tagList(tags$h4("Third iteration:")),
              plotOutput('PlotIter3'),
              tags$hr())
  )

server <- function(input, output) {
  ii <- 1
observeEvent(input$exec,{ 

  continue <- TRUE
  while(continue==TRUE){
    if(ii == 1){
      output$PlotIter1<-renderPlot({
        plot(rep(ii,50),main=ii)
      })
    }
    if(ii == 2){
      output$PlotIter2<-renderPlot({
        plot(rep(ii,50),main=ii)
      })
    }
    if(ii == 3){
      output$PlotIter3<-renderPlot({
        plot(rep(ii,50),main=ii)
      })
    }
    ii <- ii+1
    if(ii == 4){continue <- FALSE}
  }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Edit:**

By using the local() approach provided by [r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358272/r2evans) and [Gregor de Cillia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4357017/gregor-de-cillia) the issue is partially solved, but changing the server() to one closer to mine, (replacing the IF statements for other strategy FAPP equivalent) including some calculations between each plot, the problem persist and the last data are plotted in all three plots.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  y=rnorm(10,20,2)
  for (i in 1:3) {
    local({
      thisi <- i
      plotname <- sprintf("PlotIter%d", thisi)
      output[[plotname]] <<- renderPlot({
        plot(y, main=paste0("iteration: ",thisi,", mean: ",mean(y)
                            ))
        abline(h=mean(y),col=thisi)
      })
    })
    y=y+100
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For somebody in the future, the solution that I finally came with, was changing the data structure to a list in which the result of every iteration is stored, after that, every element in the list are plotted to the corresponding render plot inside a `for` cycle. Naturally, it couldn´t be possible whithout the very important things that r2evans and Gregor de Cecilia pointed out. So, this approach gives the following `server.R` function:

```
server <- function(input, output){
  y <- list()
  #First data set
  y[[1]] <- rnorm(10,20,2)
  #Simple example of iteration results storage in the list simulating an iteration like procces
    for(i in 2:3){
    y[[i]]=y[[i-1]]+100
  }

  #Plots of every result
  for(j in 1:3){
  local({
    thisi <- j
    plotname <- sprintf("PlotIter%d", thisi)
    output[[plotname]] <<- renderPlot({
      plot(y[[thisi]], main=paste0("Iteration: ",thisi,", mean: ",round(mean(y[[thisi]]),2)
      ))
      abline(h=mean(y[[thisi]]),col=thisi)
    })
  })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are actually several problems you might run into when using `renderXXX`, `reactive` or `observe` inside loops because of lazy evaluation. From my experience, the cleanest workaround is to use lapply and loop over [shiny modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) like so

```
## context server.R
lapply(1:n, function(i) { callModule(myModule, id = NS("myModule", i), moduleParam = i) })

## context: ui.R
lapply(1:n, function(i) { myModuleUI(id = NS("myModule, i), param = i)
```

For your case however, a quicker fix would be to just use `local` as suggested in the first answer [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/532). Notice that the `ii <- ii` part is necesary for this to work since it "localizes" the variable `ii`.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
  mainPanel(
    actionButton("exec", "Start!!"),
    tagList(tags$h4("First iteration:")),
    plotOutput('PlotIter1'),
    tags$hr(),
    tagList(tags$h4("Second iteration:")),
    plotOutput('PlotIter2'),
    tags$hr(),
    tagList(tags$h4("Third iteration:")),
    plotOutput('PlotIter3'),
    tags$hr())
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  ii <- 1
  observeEvent(input$exec,{ 

    continue <- TRUE

    while(continue==TRUE){
      local({
        ii <- ii

        if(ii == 1){
          output$PlotIter1<-renderPlot({
            plot(rep(ii,50),main=ii)
          })
        }
        if(ii == 2){
          output$PlotIter2<-renderPlot({
            plot(rep(ii,50),main=ii)
          })
        }
        if(ii == 3){
          output$PlotIter3<-renderPlot({
            plot(rep(ii,50),main=ii)
          })
        }
      })

      ii <- ii+1
      if(ii == 4){continue <- FALSE}
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here is a demonstration of the modularized approach

```
myModule <- function(input, output, session, moduleParam) {
  output$PlotIter <- renderPlot({
    plot(rep(moduleParam, 50), main = moduleParam)
  })
}

myModuleUI <- function(id, moduleParam) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    tags$h4(paste0("iteration ", moduleParam, ":")),
    plotOutput(ns('PlotIter')),
    tags$hr()
  )
}

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    actionButton("exec", "Start!!"),
    lapply(1:4, function(i) {myModuleUI(NS("myModule", i), i)})
  ),
  function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(
      input$exec,
      lapply(1:4, function(i) {callModule(myModule, NS("myModule", i), i)})
    )
  }
)
```

Sidenote: If you want to capture several plots from the same script, you can use `evaluate::evaluate` for that

```
library(evaluate)

plotList <- list()
i <- 0

evaluate(
  function() {
    source("path/to/script.R")
  },
  output_handler = output_handler(
    graphics = function(plot) {
      i <- i + 1
      plotList[[i]] <- plot
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: When is nesting a `renderPlot` inside `observeEvent` a good idea? The first is important for returning a value, the second for its side-effect, why combine the two concepts?

Comment: I totally agree that it is a bad idea to blindly use `renderXXX`, `callModule` or `observe` inside an `observeEvent` and I personally don't do this in any of my projects. That said, I never really saw a case where this nesting led to super slow runtimes, so I didn't mention it in my answer.

Comment: Every iteration in my script takes a little time. The user must upload a file, set some particular configurations for the calculations and then press start for the script to run and after that I want the plots to get showed. I do not really know if it is neccesary to put almost all the server.R part inside `observeEvent`. Could you please tell me why it is a bad idea? there is another way to achieve this?

Comment: If you only fire this once per upload, there is no need to worry about this IMO. You might get into trouble if you call `renderPlot` several times a second (for example, because it depends on a very "busy" reactive). Potential issues: you probably get worse performance and excessive memory usage because some JavaScript bindings have to be bound and unbound over and over again. I can add some remarks about how to solve this without dynamically writing to `output` in a few hours.

Comment: That's a fair question, CristhianParedes, and I don't know that I have a solid answer other than personal experience. I can't find one example in the [Tutorial](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/), [Gallery](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/), or [Articles](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/) on http://shiny.rstudio.com/  where they use nested blocks. I attended the 2-day [Intermediate Shiny](https://github.com/jcheng5/shiny-training-rstudioconf-2018) workshop at RStudioConf 2018, and it was never used once (by the `shiny` creators). ...

Comment: ... so I cannot state why it should not -- and without testing, I cannot say if/why/how it's bad for performance -- but I can say that if it were necessary and/or had benefits, one would think that the creators would have used it in one or more of their examples. Weak explanation at best, I know. (If I missed an example on their website, please correct me! I'm not implying expertise here, just what I'm inferring as "best-practice" from standard/perceived practice.)

Comment: ... and at the risk of turning a long answer into a series of comments ... my personal rationale is that `reactive`/`observe` blocks handle dependency automatically. It seems that since everything in an `observeEvent` is implicitly wrapped in `isolate`, the nested `reactive` blocks *should not fire on dependencies*, and if they do then it boggles my mind "*why*". If they do now, it may be that RStudio will "fix the bug" at some point (b/c things in `isolate` should not react), thereby rendering your code not-working.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that doing it with a `while` (or similar) loop is missing some reactivity potential. In fact, it looks like you are trying to force *order* of plotting within shiny's depedency/reactivity layer.

I think there should be three separate blocks, iterating as simultaneously as R/shiny will allow:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
  mainPanel(
    actionButton("exec", "Start!!"),
    tagList(tags$h4("First iteration:")),
    plotOutput('PlotIter1'),
    tags$hr(),
    tagList(tags$h4("Second iteration:")),
    plotOutput('PlotIter2'),
    tags$hr(),
    tagList(tags$h4("Third iteration:")),
    plotOutput('PlotIter3'),
    tags$hr()
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$PlotIter1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(rep(1,50),main=1)
  })
  output$PlotIter2 <- renderPlot({
    plot(rep(2,50),main=2)
  })
  output$PlotIter3 <- renderPlot({
    plot(rep(3,50),main=3)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I'll go one step further in my inference, though, that you really aren't interested in just 1-3 with this `plot`; perhaps you want to do it programmatically? (I had to look this up, because I asked a very similar question several years ago, and received a [good workaround from jcheng5](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/532#issuecomment-48008956) (one of the main authors of `shiny`).

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  for (i in 1:3) {
    local({
      thisi <- i
      plotname <- sprintf("PlotIter%d", thisi)
      output[[plotname]] <<- renderPlot({
        plot(rep(thisi, 50), main=thisi)
      })
    })
  }
}
```

This method only works, of course, if the plots are relatively identical with small changes. Otherwise, the first version up above might be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your time and your effort, but, perhaps, my MWE suffered from oversimplification of the problem, so the first approach doesn´t works for my particular case. The second one solves my issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: From your question and the answer you accepted, it seems like you only want the plots to be done once and only once, never updating. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, I want every  iteration producing a plot and in some way storing  that plot in the corresponding renderPlot for later show. In any case, despite the `local({ })` solution works well on my MWE, my program is still showing me the last produced plot n-times inshead of the one that corresponds to the respective iteration running.

Comment: *"for later show"* doesn't make sense to me. The code produces the three plots immediately, shows the plots immediately, and will never produce them again. This "later" concept does not fit how I see this working. I understand that your actual use-case is likely different than this example, so I "get" how there is more at play, but I'm not entirely following. (Plus, my answer worked for me; if you say that the other answer is not working for your actual code, then perhaps you should not accept it, instead edit your MWE/question and try again?)

Comment: The _'for later show'_ part can be ignored, sorry. I have already edited my MWE and question.